# jquery resizable return false

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have an object that has a property status="lock". The div that represents this object is resizable and draggable.

For the draggable, if i use the following logic then the dragging is effectively locked
start: {... if status==lock then return false ...}

But the same logic for resizable does not work

I can set the resizable("disabled") but was wondering if I can stop the resize within start or resize events

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can cancel a resize event from the start/resize methods.

You *can* specify a selector to which resizable events do not apply, using the `cancel` option.  With this strategy, you would have to add a class to each resizable `div` indicating whether or not you want it to be resized.

For example, lets say you had a dataset like this:

```
var data = [
    { id: 'test1', status: 'lock' },
    { id: 'test2', status: 'unlock' },
    { id: 'test3', status: 'lock' }
];
```

And you wanted to lock those items with status: "lock".  Assuming you have code that creates DOM elements from this data like this:

```
var i, length = data.length;
for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    $("body").append("<div id='" + data[i].id + "' class='resizable " + data[i].status + "'/>");
}
```

Note that elements now have a class (lock or unlock) depending on their 'status' property.

Now, you can do the following to cancel resizing on elements with a class `lock`:

`$(".resizable").resizable({ cancel: ".lock" });`

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/CDUce/

Comment: Thanks this is good approach. I accepted this as answer but for my app, I have a mousedown event, so I call evt.stoppropogation when the object flag is set to 'Lock', This way I don't have to code the resizable and draggable separately.